# Can't launch server on rails (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, webrick

I can't launch server on rails.
I uninstalled and re-installed both mysql and mysql gem.
But still I get the same error

This is what i get

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from G:/Surath/Sites/simple_cms2/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How did you install the MySQL gem?

Comment: Do you have "gem 'mysql'" in the Gemfile? Is this the error that you get when you run "rails s"?

Comment: Yes. this is the error I get when I run "rails s". And I think I've got myslq gem, because when I check the gem list I get  "Using mysql2 (0.3.11)" in the list.

Comment: can you run mysql from the command line?  it could be an error with your PATH.  Additionally, make sure you have the mysql-devel package installed.  with out it the gem may not build/work correctly.

Comment: @Ben 
Yes, mysql works in command line.
I'm not sure about the "mysql-devel package" how can I check it.

Comment: when I installed the msql gem I got -  

    You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
    It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2.
    It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid  potential issues.
    At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files where available in the following download:

    http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick
    And put lib\libmysql.dll file in your Ruby bin directory, for example C:\Ruby\bin"
 
I did it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any way that I can install any other version of mysql gem than the binary version.

Comment: how does your database.yml look like?